Prequisites for studying relational algebra:
"Hello everyone!
I'm interested in learning more about relation algebra, but I'm not sure where to start. Can someone please tell me what the prerequisites are for studying relation algebra?
Specifically, I'd like to know:

What mathematical concepts are required (e.g. set theory, group theory, etc.)?
Are there any specific programming languages or software tools that I need to be familiar with?
Are there any particular books or resources that you recommend for learning relation algebra?

Thanks in advance for your help!"
